# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPath Weird contentSize Behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rows, expand

I'm creating a custom UITableView with expand / collapse functionality. When the user taps in a table section, new rows are inserted using this code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray *arrIP = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<[rows count]; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [arrIP addObject:indexPath];

    }
}

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrIP withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Everything works fine but sometimes the tableView don't fit well to their content size. My problem is according to some cells that are drawn behind the expanded section that are touched when I'm scrolling up.

[image]

Here's the code to draw sections:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id sectionKey         =  [_dataSource objectAtIndex:section][@"section"];
    CGFloat sectionHeight = [[_dataSource objectAtIndex:section][@"header_height"] floatValue];

    if ([sectionKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [sectionKey isEqualToString:@"info"]){

        OptionCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:OptionCell.cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[OptionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:OptionCell.cellIdentifier];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }

        return cell;

    }else if ([sectionKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [sectionKey isEqualToString:@"history"]){

        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExpandedHeader" owner:self options:nil];
        ExpandedHeader *headerView = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        headerView.BTN_loadData.tag = section;
        [headerView.BTN_loadData addTarget:self action:@selector(loadData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, sectionHeight)];

        return headerView;

   }

 }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using autoreleasepool?

Comment: yeah, memory is freed once the block for ends

Comment: Ok you need to study how autoreleasepool works.

Comment: Any code for cell height and section header height?

Comment: handle insertion and deletion of new cell on this delegate method : - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

Comment: cell height and section height are handled in heightForHeaderInSection and heightForRowAtIndexPath. No changes needed in their sizes.